# AngularJS | How to render a HTML element(directive) only when condition is met?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on a `AngularJS`(1.4) project where I want to load a directive on a particular conditions.

This directives when loaded calls few APIs and display some HTML elements.

I want to call those API only if those conditions are met.

In case when conditions are not met I tried following:

1. using `ng-if`, it's not displaying the directive but it's calling the APIs.
2. using `ng-show`, it's not displaying the directive but it's calling the APIs.

I got to know that `ng-if` first adds the directive and then removes it if conditions are not met.
Here on loading of directive, APIs are being called.

Is there any way or approach to resolve this problem ?

Comment: did you try ngSwitchWhen? ng-if or ng-show will not restrict API calling as you have to restrict this from controller level.

Comment: from my experience ng-if shouldn't run your code if condition isn't met. it's better if you add a demo of your code to better understand the issue. you can however, dynamically create elements using $compile

Comment: It is hard to help with a problem with code  when the question contains none of the buggy code.

Answer (score 0):

> *I got to know that `ng-if` first adds the directive and then removes it if conditions are not met.*

The `ng-if` adds the element and its children to the DOM when the condition is `true`. If the condition, changes to `false`, the AngularJS framework removes the element from the DOM. If the condition is initially `false` and never changes to `true`, the element is never added to the DOM. The element is rendered as a comment node.